# Link to specific page in Wagtail CMS

Tags: wagtail

In Wagtail CMS I don't know how to construct a link to a specific page. I want a (fixed, not authored) link in the templates from my `BlogIndexPage` to my `BlogIndexArchivePage` and vice versa. 
In the official docs [pageurl](http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0/topics/writing_templates.html?highlight=pageurl#internal-links-tag) looks promising:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
...
<a href="{% pageurl self.blog_page %}">
```

but I don't understand the notation `blog_page`, but the `page-classes` are named like `BlogPage` or `BlogIndexPage`. Did I have to define the page I would link to in my `models.py` - and if so: how?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before I give the detailed answer, I'll make a simple suggestion: assuming you've already given your blog index and blog archive pages sensible URLs like `/blog/` and `/blog/archive/`, is there any reason to believe that they're *ever* going to change? If not, then just write a hard-coded `<a href="/blog/">` link on your template and forget about it. That might seem like a cop-out, but you're going to need *some* persistent way of nominating a particular page as the blog index - whether that's based on page type, or ID, or location within your site structure - and doing that by URL is probably more sensible and future-proof than any other mechanism you could come up with. URLs are supposed to be persistent identifiers, after all...

---

OK. The detailed answer:

In the example for the `pageurl` documentation, `self.blog_page` is simply a variable that refers to a `Page` object. It's what you'd use if you had a setup like this, where `blog_page` is a field of your page, pointing to some other page:

```
class ExamplePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()
    blog_page = models.ForeignKey('wagtailcore.Page')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body'),
        PageChooserPanel('blog_page'),
    ]
```

However, in your case, you want the linked page to be determined programmatically, not part of the authored page content, so you need some other way of obtaining the relevant `Page` object.

When you talk about "my `BlogIndexPage`", you're implying that exactly one page of that type will exist on your site at any one time. If that is indeed a valid assumption, then a suitable Django expression for retrieving that page would be: `BlogIndexPage.objects.first()`. (If that's not a valid assumption, then you'll need to decide for yourself how your site is going to pick one particular BlogIndexPage as *the* blog index.)

You now need to make that page object available on your template. One way of doing this is through a `get_context` method:

```
class ExamplePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(ExamplePage, self).get_context(request)
        context['blog_index'] = BlogIndexPage.objects.first()
        return context
```

This makes it available on the template as the variable `blog_index`, allowing you to write: `{% pageurl blog_index %}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I took the first, easy first approach, you were totally right about the uniqueness of these two URLs. But even your detailed answer helped me with another Wagtail problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried your way using get_context and it is really working. I'm just curious, this post is 4 years old...does not have wagtail some better approach nowadays? I can't find anything...

Comment: PageChooserPanel can be used to link to any wagtailcore.Page 
But how can I get the slug of that page from the parent page?

Answer (score 9):

slugurl should be much easier. For example, `{% slugurl 'blog_index'%}`

pageurl requires a page object which must be available in the questioning template.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I will definitely use this - and @gasman is also right.

Comment: How do you need to adjust the context to get the `blog_index` variable ready for `slugurl`? If I use the code from @gasman and just change `pageurl` into `slugurl`, by link coems out as <domain name>/None

Comment: First, you can check that the blog_index has value. It should be a post which has been published. Just print it out in that method to see it is right one.