# Getting the context of a specific page in Wagtail / Puput

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a Django/Wagtail/Puput site with this structure:

```
RootPage
  |
  |- BlogPage (Puput)
  |- InformationPage
```

I'm trying to display summary info from the Puput blog on the InformationPage. This works with this code, **as long as I only have one BlogPage**:

```
class InformationPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(verbose_name=_("body"))

    . . . 

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(InformationPage, self).get_context(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_page'] = BlogPage.objects.first()
        context['information_page'] = self
        return context
```

But I'm trying to make it work with more than one blog page. It seems like this should work:

```
class InformationPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(verbose_name=_("body"))
    blog_page = models.ForeignKey('wagtailcore.Page', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="information_blog")

    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("title", classname="title"),
                FieldPanel("body", classname="full"),
                PageChooserPanel('blog_page'),
            ],
            heading=_("Content"),
        )]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(InformationPage, self).get_context(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_page'] = self.blog_page
        context['information_page'] = self
        return context
```

But it doesn't. This was suggested by @gasman [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766186/link-to-specific-page-in-wagtail-cms).  In other words, if I refer to the blog page properties using `context['blog_page'] = BlogPage.objects.first()`, everything works fine, but switching it out to use `context['blog_page'] = self.blog_page` (and selecting the correct blog page in the admin) does not work.

Without switching it out, I think I can only ever have a single instance of BlogPage, because all InformationPages will have to pull from the first instance.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given a description of the problem beyond "it doesn't work", so I'm only guessing here, but you're presumably trying to output fields of the blog page that are part of the BlogPage model. This doesn't work because `blog_page` is defined as a foreign key to `wagtailcore.Page`, and so accessing `self.blog_page` only gives you a basic Page object consisting of the core fields such as `title`. You can retrieve the full BlogPage object by accessing `self.blog_page.specific`:

```
context['blog_page'] = self.blog_page.specific
```

However, a smarter approach is to change your foreign key to point to BlogPage, since presumably choosing any other page type is not valid here:

```
blog_page = models.ForeignKey('my_blog_app.BlogPage', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="information_blog")
```

With this change, `self.blog_page` will return a BlogPage instance directly, and there's no need for `.specific`.